# Image uploader working perfectly for an insert form but not for an update form

Tags: php, image, upload

I know there are already many similar questions like this and I apologize in advance for adding to the file, but I am a little short on time to do research and I need quick help. I am trying to finish an overdue assignment and my image upload function is working perfectly when I add a product, but not when I update it. I have no idea why. My code to update the image is here:

```
require_once 'file-util.php'
    // Check if the file exists before setting it
    if (isset($_FILES['imageFile1'])) {
        // Retrieve the name of the file based on what it was called on the client computer
        $filename = $codeInput . '.png';

        // Make sure the filename exists 
        if (!empty($filename)) {
            // Store the temporary location of where the file was stored on the server
            $sourceLocation = $_FILES['imageFile1']['tmp_name'];

            // Build the path to the images folder and use the same filename as before
            $targetPath = $image_dir_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

            // Move file from temp directory to images folder
            move_uploaded_file($sourceLocation, $targetPath);
        }
    }
```

This is the exact same code that I have in my insert_product file.

And my file_util is here:

```
$image_dir = 'images';
$image_dir_path = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $image_dir;
```

Everything else works perfectly, but it is just this little thing that isn't seeming to do anything, so it seems to me like there's a little detail I'm missing for this to work in update_product. Is there something else I need to do to get this to work, or is it something else I'm unaware of?

Edit: Turns out that I just forgot to set the encryption type in my add_product_form. If anyone else has this silly issue, double check your forms for this near the top of the body:

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="post"
              id="add_product_form"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Are you generating the same identical filename when you "re-upload" it. Are you seeing "new images" appearing in the folder? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: It's alright; I got it sorted out and documented the fix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your updating form tag has the proper enctype attribute value... 
and please be aware to use more validation on the uploaded file, your checking for file name exists or not will always be true as you are setting a value for it in the previous line.

Comment: It's alright; I figured out. Just forgot to set the encryption type in the form action of my update_product_form.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my code was right but I just forgot to go "enctype="multipart/form-data" in update_product_form.php.